# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher - Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to ASP.NET. I feel I have some type of jQuery conflict but I am not sure how to fix it. My site was working fine, then I tried to add an Autocomplete field in a view with this code in the view

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I get:

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4.

At first, I was unable to get the autocomplete to work it would give me a message:

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Then I found a tutorial that told me I needed to comment out the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in the _layout view. I did this and the autocomplete view started working just fine, but that is when the Bootstrap error started on my other pages.

Any Ideas? 
SEB

Here is my code from the controller and view:
View:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtempname").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/HelpDesk/getemp/",
                    data: "{'ename':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }))
                    },
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
    $.fn.jquery
</script>

<input style="width:500px" type="text" id="txtempname" name="ename" />
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getemp(string ename)
        {
            var emp = (from x in em.Employees where x.FirstName.StartsWith(ename) select new { label = x.FirstName}).ToList();
            return Json(emp);

        }
```

Comment: The bundles line will be adding jQuery to your page already. Leave it enabled. But you don't need another script tag as well. Adding jQuery twice will certainly cause issues. I suggest you read about what bundling does in MVC

Comment: (however for auto-complete you would need the additional jQuery UI package. You could add that through bundling too, rather than script tags, it's usually more efficient)

Comment: Bootstrap will need the jQuery added before it.  Use the bundles (with bootstrap) or add the script tab to the page (at the appropriate place like the layout - which is what it is great for) `Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Comment: Did you figure out how to update the jQuery version referenced by `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`?